# Misaligned Cube: How to fix?

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles, solvability

There must have been an accidental turning of corners. Now, I do not know how to turn corners, so that the cube is solvable again.

The red and blue edges are the only misaligned pieces.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I switch 2 yellow corners that are on the same face from a 3x3 cube?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78365/how-can-i-switch-2-yellow-corners-that-are-on-the-same-face-from-a-3x3-cube)  (Note that the linked question is about corners, but the answer applies here as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cube is not solvable normally from this position. A piece must have popped at some point and been replaced incorrectly. The fastest way to fix it from here is probably just to pop them again.

Comment: Yes, but which pieces do I need to pop to get it solvable again?

Comment: Pop the two ones you specified and switch them around.

Comment: @Duck: How could this be done? I was only able to turn edges.

Comment: Twist the top layer by 45° and pop out the red-white-blue corner piece. The two misaligned pieces should then slide out so they can be repositioned.

Comment: Depending on the cube, it may be easiest to pop edge pieces by turning the face 45 degrees and twisting the edge piece itself by 90 degrees.